# How to use both @react-native-community/masked-view and @react-native-masked-view/masked-view in the same project?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I use react navigation V5 which depends on @react-native-community/masked-view (v0.10.0 or above) and also want to use react-native-skeleton-placeholder v5.0.0 which uses @react-native-masked-view/masked-view (v2.3.0 or above).

When I put them both in my package.json I get the following error when running the project from the android building:

`Error: Program type already present: org.reactnative.maskedview.BuildConfig`

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best and Verified way is :**

If you are using skeleton placeholder then do these steps:

1. Go to node_modules -> react-native-skeleton-placeholder -> libs -> skeleton-placeholder.js .
2. In this file you will find a line in which masked view dependency is imported , so you just have replace it with your current masked view dependency. There is no need to download another masked view dependency.

***Happy Coding !***